# Trim a string up to 4th delimiter from right side

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have strings like following which should be parsed with only unix command (bash)

```
49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed
```

I want to trim the strings like above upto 4th underscore from end/right side. So output should be

```
49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test
```

Number of underscores can vary in overall string. For example, The string could be

```
49_sftp_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed
```

Output should be (after trimming up to 4th occurrence of underscore from right.

```
49_sftp_simul_test
```

Comment: What output do you expect for the input string `a_b_c`? Empty output or `a_b_c`?

Comment: @hek2mgl Empty output

Answer (score 4):

Easily done using `awk` that decrements `NF` i.e. no. of fields to -4 after setting input+output field separator as underscore:

```
s='49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed'

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {NF -= 4; $1=$1} 1' <<< "$s"
49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Which shell you are using ? I tried with bash on Max OS, it prints original string s. Am I missing something. Sorry, not good in scripting.

Comment: Actually it is not bash issue. I am also on OSX . This just needs gnu awk that I got using home brew installer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for that:

```
string="..."
echo "${string%_*_*_*_*}"
```

Comment: I think `4th underscore from end/right side` doesn't mean 5 fields from left

Comment: @anubhava Good point. In that case parameter expansion can be used.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(_[^_]*){4}$//' <<< "49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed"
49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test
```

From the end of line, removes 4 occurrences of `_` followed by non `_` characters.

Comment: Worked ! Thanks !

Comment: How would you get the part which was trimmed ?

Comment: You can get the trimmed part using backreference: `sed -E -n 's/.*((_[^_]*){4})$/\1/p'`

Comment: Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

**Perl one-liner**

```
echo $your-string | perl -lne '$n++ while /_/g; print join "_",((split/_/)[-$n-1..-5])'
```

**input**

```
49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed
```

**the output**
`49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test`

**input**

```
49_sftp_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed
```

**the output**

`49_sftp_simul_test`

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest but maybe the easiest to remember and funiest:

```
echo "49_sftp_mac_myfile_simul_test_9999_4000000000000001_2017-02-06_15-15-26.49.csv.failed"| 
   rev | cut -d"_" -f5- | rev
```

Comment: I don't know when I'll use it but I'm glad to know the `rev` command exists :)